# Sql join only 1 row

Tags: sql, t-sql

I want to join the table CustomerAgreementRole with only one row from AgreementRoleGroup, based on ViewPriority. Example: CustomerAgreementRole can have three rows. I only want the joined row where ViewPriority is highest

```
AgreementId, AgreementRoleId 
1            1
1            2
1            3  

CustomerAgreementRole

 1. AgreementId
 2. AgreementRoleId

AgreementRoleGroup

 1. AgreementRoleId
 2. ViewPriority
```

Current query:

```
select * from CustomerAgreementRole car 
join (select agreementRoleId, min(ViewPriority) as mi from AgreementRoleGroup group by AgreementRoleId) as arg on car.AgreementRoleId = arg.AgreementRoleId
```

Expected result:

```
AgreementId, AgreementRoleId, ViewPriority
1            1                1
```

Comment: Can you show your current query or attempt and expected result

Comment: Have you guys figured out that GL and GMB are business partners and you're allowed to take points off each other but not them?

Comment: On a side note: Names in SQL are usually case insensitive. Long names like `CustomerAgreementRole` can hence become less readable when formatted differently (`customeragreementrole`, `CUSTOMERAGREEMENTROLE `). For this reason it is common to use underscores to ensure readbility regardless of upper/lower case formatting (`customer_agreement_role`).

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Made it working with this:

```
WITH CTEViewPriority (lowestViewPriority, agreementId) as (
    select min(ViewPriority), AgreementId from CustomerAgreementRole as car 
    left join AgreementRoleGroup arg on car.AgreementRoleId = arg.AgreementRoleId
    group by agreementId
    )
select * from CustomerAgreementRole as car
inner join CTEViewPriority as arg on lowestViewPriority = arg.agreementRoleId and arg.agreementId = car.agreementId
```

Answer (score 0):

May be something like this:

```
 SELECT *
 FROM CustomerAgreementRole A
 CROSS APPLY
 (
    SELECT TOP 1 *
    FROM AgreementRoleGroup B
    WHERE A.[AgreementRoleId] = B.[AgreementRoleId]
    ORDER BY ViewPriority DESC
 ) C
```

Comment: I Tried the query. It returns all three rows, and not juse the one I want

Answer (score 0):

Since AgreementRoleGroup already got AgreementRoleId we can just `join` with some subquery

```
select a.*, b2.ViewPriority from CustomerAgreementRole a left join 
(
  select b.AgreementRoleId, b.ViewPriority 
  from AgreementRoleGroup b 
  where b.ViewPriority = 
  (
    select min(ViewPriority) 
    from AgreementRoleGroup
  )
) b2
on a.AgreementRoleId=b2.AgreementRoleId
```

But I'll say that using `min()` isn't the best way,you should use `top` in @gotqn answer but right now this will work.

re-edit

```
create table CustomerAgreementRole (AgreementId int,AgreementRoleId int);
insert into CustomerAgreementRole values (1,1);
insert into CustomerAgreementRole values (2,3);
insert into CustomerAgreementRole values (3,4);
insert into CustomerAgreementRole values (4,2);

create table AgreementRoleGroup (AgreementRoleId int, ViewPriority int);
insert into AgreementRoleGroup values (1,3);
insert into AgreementRoleGroup values (3,4);
insert into AgreementRoleGroup values (4,2);
insert into AgreementRoleGroup values (2,1);
```

I use those as sample data and got this result [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=a5d55e5740c1cedf0fc35013da80f01c)

if you just want that one row and don't care ViewPriority need to be min, use `top` instead

```
select top 1 a.*, b.ViewPriority from CustomerAgreementRole a left join 
AgreementRoleGroup b
on a.AgreementRoleId=b.AgreementRoleId
order by ViewPriority asc
```

Comment: yeah I just edit again cause realize some variable is miss type. I use a and b as your table when testing.

Comment: It now gave me all three rows, but no viewPriority in any of them

Comment: @Sindresvends re-edit with some online db simulator and result, might because your table AgreementRoleGroup store data in different way.

Comment: Changed the input data for CustomerAgreementRole, since I have several rows with same agreementId and different agremeentRoles. I just want the one row matching the lowest viewPriority. In my database i get all rows, but no one has viewPriority.
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=41360bad8b21a181a0370d3563bd3f55

Comment: your example already get that one row with ViewPriority,I edit some code if you only want that one row with ViewPriority,but since you say your database got no ViewPriority at all then the problem is not the code. is your data.

Comment: @Sindresvends you need to give us some more info about your data. Otherwise I see no reason why the code didn't get what you want since it  also worked in simulator.

Comment: Yes, I changed the input to match mine now: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=512c1ce07fef664e3279df87cef5d089

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223615/discussion-between-t-peter-and-sindresvends).

Answer (score 0):

Per AgreementId you want the AgreementRoleId with the highest priority (lowest ViewPriority value). This means you want to rank the CustomerAgreementRole rows and only show the best ranked ones. Ranking is typically done with `ROW_NUMBER`, `RANK` or `DENSE_RANK` in SQL.

```
select AgreementId, AgreementRoleId, ViewPriority
from
(
  select
    car.AgreementId, car.AgreementRoleId, arg.ViewPriority,
    row_number() over (partition by car.AgreementId order by arg.ViewPriority) as rn
  from CustomerAgreementRole car
  join AgreementRoleGroup arg on arg.AgreementRoleId = car.AgreementRoleId
) ranked
where rn = 1;
```